# Customize cli-generated feathersjs services

Tags: javascript, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm writing an api to try featherjs with its mongoose adapter. I want my `GET /books/` endpoint to only return books with the `private` attribute set to false. Should I use a *before* hook? If that's the case, how do I prevent users from running custom queries in my endpoint? Should I manually empty the `params` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a ***before*** hook in `books.hooks.js`

```
const books_qry = require('../../hooks/books_qry');

module.exports = {
  before: {
   all: [],
   find: [books_qry()],
   ...
```

Create `/src/hooks/books_qry.js`

```
module.exports = function () {
  return function (context) {
     //You have 2 choices to change the context.params.query

     //overwrite any request for a custom query
     context.params.query =  { private: false };

     //or add a query param to the request for a custom query
     context.params.query.private = false

     //check the updated context.params.query 
     console.log(context.params.query); 

     return context;
  }
}
```

Select one of the choices that you need. Since I never used mongoose at the moment, check the documentation in order to create a valid query (btw above example works for mongodb adapter)